# How to skip unzipping a file that already exists?

Tags: bash

I have a for loop which unzips all `.zip` into that directory. I want to check if the unzipped file already exists and do the unzipping for only the zipped files.

Here is the code without any if statment:

```
for i in `cat zipfiles.txt`; do
    output_dir=$(dirname $i)
    unzip -d $output_dir $i
done
```

zipfiles.txt is like:

```
./CSAN/S1A.zip 
./MEZO/S1B.zip
```

output is

```
./CSAN/S1A.SAFE 
./MEZO/S1B.SAFE
```

I tried to add an `if` loop, but it's still asking if I want to replace the already existing file.

```
for i in `cat zipfiles.txt`; do
    file="${dir%/}.SAFE"
    if [ -e "$file" ]
    then
        echo "It exists"
    else
        output_dir=$(dirname $i)
        unzip -d $output_dir $i
    fi
done
```

What is the good solution?

Comment: Your bash script is off

Answer (score 23):

Use the `-n` switch. From the unzip man page:

> -n     never overwrite existing files.  If a file already exists, skip the extraction of that file without prompting.  By
>                 default  unzip  queries  before extracting any file that already exists; the user may choose to overwrite only the
>                 current file, overwrite all files, skip extraction of the current file, skip extraction of all existing files,  or
>                 rename the current file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 
I found the right solution:

```
for i in `cat zipfiles.txt`; do
    output_dir=$(dirname $i)
    echo $output_dir
    file="${i/zip/SAFE}"
    echo $file
    if [ -e "$file" ]
    then
        echo "It exists"
    else
        unzip -d $output_dir $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is substantially different from the commands in your question. Could you please explain exactly what you changed?